# Topologies showing up in Storm UI but logs not generating

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm, topology

I have one nimbus and 3 supervisors. Yesterday I did following changes in the nimbus server:
- Added one more supervisor to nimbus
- Edited zoo.cfg
- Kafka has got upgraded to 0.9.6 from 0.9.5

After all these, I can see my topologies running in Storm UI but they are not generating any log files. 
The nimbus logs says:

```
2016-04-20T09:43:15.738+0000 b.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Uploading file from client to /var/storm/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-6fe107ab-336a-4103-a265-2594f009ebe1.jar
2016-04-20T09:43:16.136+0000 b.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Finished uploading file from client: /var/storm/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-6fe107ab-336a-4103-a265-2594f009ebe1.jar
2016-04-20T09:43:16.151+0000 b.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Received topology submission for DRELoaderTopology with conf {"storm.id" "DRELoaderTopology-9-1461145396", "topology.acker.executors" nil, "topology.kryo.decorators" (), "topology.name" "DRELoaderTopology", "topology.max.spout.pending" 1, "topology.debug" true, "topology.kryo.register" nil, "topology.message.timeout.secs" 1000, "topology.workers" 1, "topology.max.task.parallelism" nil}
2016-04-20T09:43:16.417+0000 b.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Activating DRELoaderTopology: DRELoaderTopology-9-1461145396
2016-04-20T09:43:16.557+0000 b.s.s.EvenScheduler [INFO] Available slots: (["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6702] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6703] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6704] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6705] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6706] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6707] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6708] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6709] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6710] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6711] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6712] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6713] ["2a563b51-52b1-42a2-87a0-1527d783c89f" 6714] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6702] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6703] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6704] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6705] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6706] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6707] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6708] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6709] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6710] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6711] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6712] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6713] ["df994e6f-7c6c-45db-8036-d2e094509c2e" 6714] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6702] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6703] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6704] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6705] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6706] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6707] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6708] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6709] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6710] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6711] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6712] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6713] ["9e107b90-68a8-4bbd-8d1b-fd29853dc733" 6714] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6702] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6703] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6704] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6705] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6706] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6707] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6708] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6709] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6710] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6711] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6712] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6713] ["9e88aeee-4e17-4ac0-9fef-b87d2c09df1e" 6714])
```

Don't know what is happening here.

Comment: Check supervisor log. Does your topology create any workers? Maybe you messed up with workers setting, do you see any free slots in storm UI?